# Working with LazyList by Fedor onitemclick implementation

Tags: android, eclipse, image, listview

I will sound stupid to most of you by asking this, but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own and can't pass to my next task until I found an answer.
So far I have downloaded the LazyList project from https://github.com/thest1/LazyList made by Fedor, I'm trying to understand how it works so I can implement it on my own project. My problem is that I don't know where to implement the onitemclicklistener part:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onitemClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()public   void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
noteId= //the item id from the list
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), noteId, 2000).show();
}
```

I have try to add it on my mainActivity but then I can't find how to connect to my LazyAdapter to find the item id to be displayed in a toast. My project will contain some other information in the list (as a table several columns) so I want to be able to access an specific columns from that rows using the item id. and testing with a simple toast will help.
Thanks, I hope you don't laugh to much and help me a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about it in the wrong manner: [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) is an interface and the `onItemClick()` method takes four parameters... I assume this is what you are trying to do:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id + "", 2000).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: the LazyAdapter.java is a different file from the mainActivity.java thats why I can't find a way to do the connection

Comment: That is fine. The ListView has a link to its adapter, in fact the `id` parameter in `onItemClick()` refers to the id provided by LazyAdapter

Comment: but since id is long can't be turn into text

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. You can use `id + ""` or `String.valueOf(id)` to convert a primitive data type like `long` into a String.